# Syntax "Selector" Swift 2.2

Tags: swift

I'm trying to fix my NSNotificationCenter and its not working

**the message :**

```
'Use of string literal for Objective-C selectors is deprecated; use '#selector' instead'.
```

**the line :**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, Selector :#selector(GameViewController.goBack)(GameViewController.goBack), object: nil)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@Eendje's answer is incorrect by its first comment.

I think it is better answer.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, #selector(self.goBack), name: "your notification name", object: nil)
```

If some actions has target, it should be presented like `#selector(target.method)` or `#selector(target.method(_:))`

Here is another example

```
UIGestureRecognizer(target: target action:#selector(target.handleGesture(_:))
```

Answer (score 8):

The code you pasted doesn't make any sense:

```
Selector :#selector(GameViewController.goBack)(GameViewController.goBack) // ???
```

It should be:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, #selector(goBack), name: "your notification name", object: nil)
```

Comment: This is also incorrect. You're adding an observer, `self`, but passing in a class or static level function `goBack`. To get a reference to an instance function like `addSubview` on `UIView`, you have to do `let view = UIView()` `let functionVariable = view.addSubview(_:)`

Comment: and what about NSNotification parameter with the selector? Is it still (_:) ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to look at this: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md

The `#selector` proposal was made in conjunction with another proposal, specifying swift functions by their argument labels. So if I have a struct:

```
struct Thing
    func doThis(this: Int, withOtherThing otherThing: Int) {

    }
}
```

I would reference that function like:

```
let thing = Thing()
thing.doThis(_:withOtherThing:)
```

Remember here I'm referencing the function itself, not calling it.

You would use that with #selector:

```
#selector(self.doThis(_:withOtherThing:)
```

Function with no arguments:

```
#selector(self.myFunction)
```

Function with one implicit argument:

```
#selector(self.myOtherFunction(_:))
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in Swift 2.2 the string literals for selectors is deprecated, and instead there this new operator #selector that you need to be using.

Refer this proposal of #selector with good examples here:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md

Answer (score -2):

Add @objc to your selector method:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "YOUR_SELECTOR_METHOD:", name: "your notification name", object: nil)

@objc func YOUR_SELECTOR_METHOD(notification: NSNotification) {
//your code
}
```

Comment: This is a bad way of doing things. Just because you can do it, doesn't mean that you should. The less-error prone way is to use `#selector`