# Use of string literal for Objective-C selectors is deprecated, use '#selector' instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have the following code:

```
func setupShortcutItems(launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    var shouldPerformAdditionalDelegateHandling: Bool = false

    if (UIApplicationShortcutItem.respondsToSelector("new")) {
        self.configDynamicShortcutItems()

        // If a shortcut was launched, display its information and take the appropriate action
        if let shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
            // When the app launched at the first time, this block can not called.
            self.handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)

            // This will block "performActionForShortcutItem:completionHandler" from being called.
            shouldPerformAdditionalDelegateHandling = false
        } else {
            // normal app launch process without quick action
            self.launchWithoutQuickAction()
        }
    } else {
        // Less than iOS9 or later
        self.launchWithoutQuickAction()
    }

    return shouldPerformAdditionalDelegateHandling
}
```

I get the following "warning" on `UIApplicationShortcutItem.respondsToSelector("new")`, which says:

> Use of string literal for Objective-c selectors is deprecated, use '#selector' instead

The warning replaces the code automatically with:

`UIApplicationShortcutItem.respondsToSelector(#selector(FBSDKAccessToken.new))`

However this doesn't compile because `new()` is unavailabe.
What am I supposed to use in this case?

Comment: check this ... may be you got something  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147831/syntax-selector-swift-2-2

Comment: Why are you testing for the selector `new`? I don't see any code that sends the `new` message here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Xcode 7.3 using swift for iOS9.3/watchOS2.2/...

If you previously used this line of code:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateResult:", name: "updateResult", object: nil)
```

you should now use this line of code:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(InterfaceController.updateResult(_:)), name: "updateResult", object: nil)
```

at least this is what Xcode offered me after I changed around a few characters in the code. Seems like it doesn't always offer the correct solution when you are presented with this error.

Comment: This worked for me, better than the selected answer.

Comment: `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.onClickStart), for: .touchUpInside)`     I use this one. Thank you !    @Florian Uhlemann

Answer (score 9):

Create a protocol whose only reason for existing is to allow you to construct the appropriate selector.  In this case:

```
@objc protocol NewMenuItemHandling {
  func new()
}
```

You are taking the informal protocol (an object that responds to the new selector) and making it into a formal protocol.

Then where you want to use the selector you can add the expression:

```
#selector(NewMenuItemHandling.new)
```

Comment: Devilishly sneaky.

Comment: I don't know that I would call it sneaky.  Basically Objective-C relies a lot on informal protocols (or Duck Typing if you prefer).  Swift wants to be a bit more formal about protocols.  So you've taken an informal protocol and told Swift that it exists :-)

Answer (score 3):

In this special `respondsToSelector` situation, where you have no existing method with which to associate a function reference, write this:

```
UIApplicationShortcutItem.respondsToSelector(Selector("new"))
```

You'll still get a warning (you shouldn't, and I've filed a bug against it), but it will be a different warning and you can ignore it.

Comment: The real joke is that you _should_ be able to get out of this by saying `#selector(NSObject.new)`, since that really is the `new` you mean. But when you say that, you get an error instead of a warning!

Comment: @gotnull Here's Apple's reply to my bug report: "Engineering has determined that your bug report (24815319) is a duplicate of another issue (24791200) and will be closed." Please, feel free to pile on: the more duplicates, the better.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, every "selector: function or object" is now "selector: #selector(class.funtion(_:))" wherever used.